# Need Help Creating a Specific UI Element

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm new to Swift and iOS development, and I'm trying to create a specific UI element that I saw in an image, but I'm not sure how to approach it in Swift. I've attached the image for reference.[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1UUZ.png)

Could someone guide me on how to create this UI element using Swift?
Thank you!

I tried using this UIBezierPath but im not able get the desired result.

```
class CustomBubbleView: UIView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        // Custom initialization
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let radius: CGFloat = 10
        let triangleWidth: CGFloat = 20
        let triangleHeight: CGFloat = 20
        
        // Create the path for the triangle and the rounded rectangle
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        
        // Start with the triangle part
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: rect.height / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height / 2 + triangleHeight / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: rect.height / 2 + triangleHeight / 2))
        
        // Continue with the rounded rectangle part
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth + radius, y: rect.height / 2 + triangleHeight / 2 + radius),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: CGFloat.pi * 1.5,
                    endAngle: CGFloat.pi,
                    clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: rect.height - radius))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth + radius, y: rect.height - radius),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: CGFloat.pi,
                    endAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2,
                    clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width - radius, y: rect.height))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.width - radius, y: rect.height - radius),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2,
                    endAngle: 0,
                    clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: radius))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.width - radius, y: radius),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: 0,
                    endAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2,
                    clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth + radius, y: 0))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth + radius, y: radius),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2,
                    endAngle: -CGFloat.pi,
                    clockwise: false)
        path.close()
        
        // Set the stroke color to gray
        UIColor.gray.setStroke()
        
        // Set the fill color to white
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        
        // Draw the filled path
        path.fill()
        
        // Draw the path with stroke
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

result of current code [current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkhRZ.png)

Comment: What's your current result with your code?

Comment: Show us the results of your current code and how it fails to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer works where the triangle is drawn with pointy corners. If you want rounded corners on all three corners of the triangle, please see my more complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77528180/20287183).

Your code is close. The first two lines of the triangle are incorrect and you need to remove the first call to `addArc`.

Replace the first two "triangle" lines with:

```
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: rect.height / 2 - triangleHeight / 2))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height / 2))
```

In those two lines the `y` parameters needed to be fixed.

You are also drawing 5 arcs when the rounded rectangle only has 4. Remove your first call to `addArc`. With those changes you get a rounded rectangle with a pointy triangle.

Here's the complete `draw` method with those changes:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let radius: CGFloat = 10
    let triangleWidth: CGFloat = 20
    let triangleHeight: CGFloat = 20

    // Create the path for the triangle and the rounded rectangle
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    // Start with the triangle part
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: rect.height / 2 - triangleHeight / 2))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height / 2))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: rect.height / 2 + triangleHeight / 2))

    // Continue with the rounded rectangle part
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: rect.height - radius))
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth + radius, y: rect.height - radius),
                radius: radius,
                startAngle: CGFloat.pi,
                endAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2,
                clockwise: false)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width - radius, y: rect.height))
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.width - radius, y: rect.height - radius),
                radius: radius,
                startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2,
                endAngle: 0,
                clockwise: false)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: radius))
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.width - radius, y: radius),
                radius: radius,
                startAngle: 0,
                endAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2,
                clockwise: false)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth + radius, y: 0))
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth + radius, y: radius),
                radius: radius,
                startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2,
                endAngle: -CGFloat.pi,
                clockwise: false)
    path.close()

    // Set the stroke color to gray
    UIColor.gray.setStroke()

    // Set the fill color to white
    UIColor.white.setFill()

    // Draw the filled path
    path.fill()

    // Draw the path with stroke
    path.stroke()
}
```

Comment: If you look closely at the OPs drawing, the "triangle" has a rounded tip. That is tricky to create, and either requires a bunch of pretty hairy math, or the use of the CGPath method `addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:)`. **That** requires rewriting the path code using CGPath. I did that in my answer in order to achieve the rounded tip of the triangle.

Comment: @DuncanC I was aware of the OP's drawing but since their code made no attempt at the rounded triangle, I didn't bother either.

Comment: I think the OP was trying to create the rounded tip in their code, but put it in the wrong place.

Comment: @HangarRash, I appreciate your valuable input, thank you.

Comment: @SakthiNathan I just updated my answer. Please see the new first paragraph with a link to a more sophisticated answer that gives a much better result where the corners of the triangle are also rounded.

Answer (score 0):

In general you want to avoid overriding a view's `draw(_:)` method. It's much better to create a shape layer and add that to your view's layer, then let the system draw it for you. (iOS drawing is optimized to use Core Animation layers.)

In any case, the tricky bit for your shape in the rounded corner of your triangle. To get a rounded corner like that you either need to do a bunch of very confusing math to figure out the start and end points of the curve, or use the `CGPath` method `addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:)`. That method does the hard work for you. (Most path drawing methods are nearly identical between CGPath and UIBezierPath, but that one is not implemented in UIBezierPath.)

Rewriting your drawRect method using CGPaths might look like this:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    
    let radius: CGFloat = 10.0
    let triangleRadius = 5.0
    let triangleWidth: CGFloat = 20
    let triangleHeight: CGFloat = 30
    
    // Create the path for the triangle and the rounded rectangle
    let cgPath = CGMutablePath()
    
    cgPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: rect.height/2 + triangleHeight/2))
    cgPath.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth + radius, y: rect.height - radius),
                  radius: radius,
                  startAngle: CGFloat.pi,
                  endAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2,
                  clockwise: true,
                  transform: .identity)
    
    cgPath.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.width - radius, y: rect.height - radius),
                  radius: radius,
                  startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2,
                  endAngle: 0,
                  clockwise: true,
                  transform: .identity)
    cgPath.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.width - radius, y: radius),
                  radius: radius,
                  startAngle: 0,
                  endAngle: 3 * CGFloat.pi / 2,
                  clockwise: true,
                  transform: .identity)
    
    cgPath.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth + radius, y: radius),
                  radius: radius,
                  startAngle: 3 * CGFloat.pi / 2,
                  endAngle: CGFloat.pi,
                  clockwise: true,
                  transform: .identity)
    cgPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: rect.height / 2 - triangleHeight / 2))
    
    cgPath.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height / 2), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: rect.height / 2 + triangleHeight / 2), radius: triangleRadius)
    cgPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: rect.height / 2 + triangleHeight / 2))
    
    // Convert our CGPath to a UIBezierPath
    let path = UIBezierPath(cgPath: cgPath)
    
    // Set the stroke color to gray
    UIColor.gray.setStroke()
    
    // Set the fill color to cyan so we can see the fill
    UIColor.cyan.setFill()
    
    // Draw the filled path
    path.fill()
    
    // Draw the path with stroke
    path.stroke()
}
```

And the results would look like this:

[image]

I changed the fill color to cyan so you can see it.

### Edit:

I rewrote the above to use a `CAShapeLayer` rather than overriding `draw(_:)`. I also made the view draw itself with a blue border and a very light gray background and inset the bubble slightly so you can see what's going on:

Here is the whole `CustomBubbleView` class:

```
//
//  CustomBubbleView.swift
//  CustomBubbleView
//
//  Created by Duncan Champney on 11/21/23.
//

import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

class CustomBubbleView: UIView {
    
    let radius: CGFloat = 10.0
    let triangleRadius = 5.0
    let triangleWidth: CGFloat = 20
    let triangleHeight: CGFloat = 30


    var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            print("In didSet")
            shapeLayer.frame = bounds.insetBy(dx: 10, dy: 10)
            shapeLayer.path = path
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        // Custom initialization
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1)
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }
    
    var path: CGPath  {
        let cgPath = CGMutablePath()
        
        cgPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: shapeLayer.bounds.height/2 + triangleHeight/2))
        cgPath.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth + radius, y: shapeLayer.bounds.height - radius),
                      radius: radius,
                      startAngle: CGFloat.pi,
                      endAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2,
                      clockwise: true,
                      transform: .identity)
        
        cgPath.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: shapeLayer.bounds.width - radius, y: shapeLayer.bounds.height - radius),
                      radius: radius,
                      startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2,
                      endAngle: 0,
                      clockwise: true,
                      transform: .identity)
        cgPath.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: shapeLayer.bounds.width - radius, y: radius),
                      radius: radius,
                      startAngle: 0,
                      endAngle: 3 * CGFloat.pi / 2,
                      clockwise: true,
                      transform: .identity)
        
        cgPath.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth + radius, y: radius),
                      radius: radius,
                      startAngle: 3 * CGFloat.pi / 2,
                      endAngle: CGFloat.pi,
                      clockwise: true,
                      transform: .identity)
        cgPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: shapeLayer.bounds.height / 2 - triangleHeight / 2))
        
        cgPath.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: 0, y: shapeLayer.bounds.height / 2), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: shapeLayer.bounds.height / 2 + triangleHeight / 2), radius: triangleRadius)
        cgPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: shapeLayer.bounds.height / 2 + triangleHeight / 2))

        return cgPath
    }
     /*
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let radius: CGFloat = 10
        let triangleWidth: CGFloat = 20
        let triangleHeight: CGFloat = 20

        // Create the path for the triangle and the rounded rectangle
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        // Start with the triangle part
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: rect.height / 2 - triangleHeight / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: rect.height / 2 + triangleHeight / 2))

        // Continue with the rounded rectangle part
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth, y: rect.height - radius))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth + radius, y: rect.height - radius),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: CGFloat.pi,
                    endAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2,
                    clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width - radius, y: rect.height))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.width - radius, y: rect.height - radius),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2,
                    endAngle: 0,
                    clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: radius))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.width - radius, y: radius),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: 0,
                    endAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2,
                    clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth + radius, y: 0))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: triangleWidth + radius, y: radius),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2,
                    endAngle: -CGFloat.pi,
                    clockwise: false)
        path.close()

        // Set the stroke color to gray
        UIColor.gray.setStroke()

        // Set the fill color to white
        UIColor.white.setFill()

        // Draw the filled path
        path.fill()

        // Draw the path with stroke
        path.stroke()
    }
*/
}
```

And the results look like this:

[image]

(I changed the fill color to cyan so you can see it.)

Comment: Duncan, your assistance is greatly appreciated. This approach is effective.